# "Thermal Bar" plot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a plot with a single vertical bar (colored continuously), with a mark on it showing the score for a particular person. Image:

[image: Thermal barplot]

I can generate the colored bar in ggplot, but only as a legend (not the actual plot). For example the legend resulting from the following is fine:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, color=mpg)) + 
geom_point() +
scale_color_gradientn(colors = rainbow(5))
```

Is there any way to do this? Any help would be really appreciated - I'm completely stuck on this.

Comment: May be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26244408/r-how-to-create-single-column-table-heatmap) helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ggplot(data.frame(y = 51), aes( y=y)) + 
  geom_tile(data = data.frame(y = 0:100),
            aes(x= 0.5, y = y, fill = y)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=0, xend=1, yend=y)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = y, x = 1), hjust = -0.3) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off", xlim = c(0,1.2)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = rainbow(5)) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = NULL) +
  guides(fill = FALSE) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(line = element_blank()) +
  labs(x="", y = "")
```

[image]